# How to enable OpenMP without -fopenmp flag?

Tags: c++, g++, openmp, intel, icc

On some Online Judge platforms, codes are compile and run in such way:

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++17 a.cpp
./a.out
```

I want to use OpenMp to parallelize my code, so is it possible to enable OpenMP without -fopenmp flag?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I've tried added this to source code, but it doesn't work:

```
#pragma GCC optimize("openmp")
```

**update**: The code above is a terrible example, here's another program that can be accelerated by parallelization:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();;
    double sum = 0;
    int n = 2e9;
    //std::cin >> n;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += sqrt(i);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I‘ve updated the question.

Comment: What do you expect to hear, other than: You can't? Forget about OpenMP, use the parallel algorithms which are part of STL since C++17.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Comment: `cout<<` is a pretty terrible example of something you'd want to parallelize!  To preserve the semantics of the program (produce the same output), every `cout <<` operation has to happen in source order.  (And will have to do locking to control access to the I/O buffer for that stream anyway, which a purely single-threaded process might have avoided).  **GCC wouldn't auto-parallelize *this* even if you *did* use `-fopenmp`.**

Comment: Thanks, it’s a terrible example. I’ve updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

Why are you parallelizing your code? Online Judge problems are supposed to be solved sequentially. The challenge of the problem is to reduce the [run time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). Online Judge should not allow this cause simply that defeats the purpose of competitive programming.

Furthermore, if you think a parallel algorithm will run faster than a sequential one for N=100, you are displaying a remarkable ignorance about parallelization overhead. Parallelizing algorithms come with huge synchronization costs that will halt performance.

Stream I/O like this can't parallelize; it has to run in source order to produce the same output.  And `cout::operator<<` is thread-safe so it has to do locking anyway to protect the stream buffer.

One way to run faster your loop is to turn off synchronization of iostream with C stdio buffers, and don't flush `cout` after every line:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

---

One more thing, `std::endl` is equivalent to outputting a `'\n` and an explicit flush of the stream (making a system call).  The online judge program presumably runs it with output redirected to a file or pipe, so `cout` will be full-buffered, not automatically flushing on every newline.  A large fraction of the cost of running this program (other than dynamic linker startup) is the system calls to do I/O, so forcing a flush on every line could make it 100x slower.

Even faster might be to prepare a single long string in a buffer to avoid the overhead of locking / unlocking `cout` twice for every line, but that's minor.  Normally the cost of I/O isn't a major factor in competitive programming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: And equally / more importantly, use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`.  Forcing an actual flush (write system call) on every line is deadly for performance vs. full-buffered output (which will be the case for stdout when writing to a file or pipe).  Most of the cost of the whole program will be the system calls, so (not counting dynamic linker startup overhead) it's 100x worse.  Choosing the name `std::endl` for that functionality (newline and flush) was a really bad design decision.

Comment: Yes, I should consider time complexity first, but I’m curious about if there’s a way to optimize a brute force solution with parallelization.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, if you want to, please go ahead edit my answer and add this. Thank you.